# Can someone recommend a relatively small device that can move a 2 1/2 inch sphere weighing 6 oz 20 feet?

Tags: solenoid

I am trying to find a method (solenoid?) by which I can strike and move a 2 1/2 inch ball that weighs 6oz with enough force to propel it up to 20 feet. Can a solenoid do this?

I would not want to propel it 20 feet all the time, so is there a solenoid application (if that's the answer) that can be moderated relatively easily (amount of current applied)? I would want the stroke to be approx. 5 inches.

I looked at a linear actuator on a web site, but that seems to be a slow mechanical movement, whereas I need more of a 'poking' type action from a relatively small device - up to 6 inches square, though to accomplish this task I would use whatever is necessary.

Comment: \${{6 \text{oz} \cdot 20 \text{ft} \cdot 9.8\text{ms}^{-2}} \over 5\text{in}} = 80\text{N}\$

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'd upvote twice if I could.

Comment: 20 ft straight up, or 20 ft rolling, like mini-golf?  Have you considered some sort of air cannon?

Comment: So basically, you want an automatic pinball launcher. For a bigger pinball.

Comment: Sounds like a pool-playing robot.

Comment: Could also go the mechanical route; use a gear-reduced motor to wind up a strong spring several turns, then a solenoid to disengage a "firing" mechanism. To get 80N out of a solenoid will require one beefy solenoid (and power for it.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. I did in fact decide to do as tomnexus suggested....an air cannon.
And yes Dave Tweed - a pool playing robot. great guess!

Comment: At first I thought this was just a "thank you" answer but see you were referring to a comment. Posting your own answer is fine and encouraged but it might be worth adding a little more detail on the air cannon and anything else that might be useful for others in the future.